# showing more than 100 users in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, list, listview, plugins

I'm trying to show more than 100 users profile in my website it's like a list that every user has he's own specification and some fields like major or etc
that I need to put filter for them which if I select a filter all of users with that filter shows.

I've searched wordpress.org and google for it but I coudn't find a usefull plugin for this job.

Any idea how to do this ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a php code to filter or search those users for you from mysql and load this code with iframe into your post, i've did this once and worked perfectly for me.

Comment: I'll check and try it and let you know